# How to get all possible user parameters using Linkedin android SDK?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn Android SDK with my app to authenticate LinkedIn users. I am having issues retrieving the full information about a user from LinkedIn.

Can someone help me get all possible parameters from LinkedIn? I am only able to get the access token.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please post your efforts, see also: how to ask question stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the token you need to send a `GET` request to:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
```

This will return the first name and last name of the user. To get aditional field you can add them as query parameter.
ex.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json
```

will also return id, number of connections and profile pic url.

You can find the full list of parameters [here.](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile) Check out the [LinkedIn rest console](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest-console) for more examples and templates.

Using the LinkedIn SDK for calling the API:

```
String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)";

APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
apiHelper.getRequest(this, url, new ApiListener() {
    @Override
    public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
        // Success!
    }

    @Override
    public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
        // Error making GET request!
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the error I am getting.  {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Extra input at the end of inline filter {(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,industry,positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes)),num-results)}",
  "requestId": "-----------",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1450284271953
}

Comment: @GassanAhmad 400 indicates a client error. There is something wrong with your request parameters. Make sure everything is OK. Try first with 1 or 2... add them one by one until you find out where you mistake is.